# Layout of three JPanels in A JFrame

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager

I have one Object-Jpanel and two Jpanel in Jframe how to add this object in to two jpanel in Jframe. I tried and just one of them add this object
add one panel-object into three frame how to do that?
I've tried and just one of them added this object.

```
    pnmnf = new pnlMemuFilm(pnlRoom1.getX() * 25 / 100, pnlRoom1.getHeight());
    pnmnf.setBounds(pnlRoom1.getX() * 75 / 100, 0, pnlRoom1.getX() * 25 / 100, pnlRoom1.getHeight());
    tbMovieSchedule = new Table();
    tbMovieSchedule.setBounds(0, 0, x * 75 / 100, y * 30 / 100);

    tbMovieScheduleTemp = new Table();
    tbMovieScheduleTemp.setBounds(0, y * 70 / 100, x * 75 / 100, y * 30 / 100);

    pnlRoom1.add(tbMovieScheduleTemp);
    pnlRoom2.add(tbMovieScheduleTemp);
    pnlRoom3.add(tbMovieScheduleTemp);

    pnlRoom1.add(tbMovieSchedule);
    pnlRoom2.add(tbMovieSchedule);
    pnlRoom3.add(tbMovieSchedule);

    pnlRoom1.add(pnmnf);
    pnlRoom2.add(pnmnf);
    pnlRoom3.add(pnmnf);
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
 including the information about [mcve]

Comment: You may find this useful: [A Visual Guide to Layout Managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html)

Comment: A Swing component can only be added to a single JPanel. I have no idea what a "Table" is since that is not a standard Swing component. If it is like a JTable, then the solution is to share the TableModel and create 3 JTable instances using the same TableModel. So the general answer to your question is to share the "model" not the "component".

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used. 3) Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) ..

Comment: ..  along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556).